# Retrieve the dimensions of an image in the filesystem

Tags: java, image, image-processing

How can I retrieve the dimensions of an image (typically jpeg, png, jpg and gif), in the local filesystem with Java?

Comment: DYM 'an image' as in **1** image, or DYM hundreds (or thousands) of images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use java's image class to get image attributes. Here is the sample -

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("imageFilePath"));
int height = img.getHeight();
int width = img.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 6):

how about this: [getting image metadata](http://johnbokma.com/java/obtaining-image-metadata.html)